# Difference between pseudo-manifolds and quasi-manifolds

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, simplicial-complex

What is exactly a **pseudo-manifold**? I read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudomanifold), and according to it a pseudo-manifold is a finite simplicial complex with the following conditions hold:

> 1. (pure) $X = |K|$ is the union of all $n$-simplices.
> 2. Every $(n – 1)$-simplex is a face of exactly two $n$-simplices for $n > 1$.
> 3. For every pair of $n$-simplices $σ, σ' \in K$, there is a sequence of $n$-simplices $σ = σ_0, σ_1, …, σ_k = σ'$ such that the
>      intersection $σ_i ∩ σ_{i+1}$ is an $(n − 1)$-simplex for all $i$. [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudomanifold)]

...but condition $3$ it is still not completely clear to me. Even more confusing, an another definition says

> A regular $(d-1)$-connected $d$-complex in which all $(d-1)$-simplices
>   are manifold simplices is called a combinatorial pseudomanifold. [[2](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/223518689_Decomposing_non-manifold_objects_in_arbitrary_dimensions)]

Are combinatorial pseudomanifold and pseudomanifold two different things?

---

Regarding **quasi-manifolds**, it's much harder to find a proper definition. The only one I found is

> A regular $h$-complex in which the star of every vertex is
>   $(h-1)$-manifold-connected is called an initial quasi-manifold. [[2](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/223518689_Decomposing_non-manifold_objects_in_arbitrary_dimensions)]

How is a quasi-manifold different from a pseudo-manifold?

Comment: The first reference should be treated as standard, the reference [2] is some applied math paper and these tend to be unreliable. The importance of the condition (3) is that it implies that $H_n(X,Z)\cong Z$ or $H_n(X,Z_2)\cong Z_2$, in other words, your $X$ has a well-defined fundamental class.

Comment: @MoisheCohen So if I have two tetrahedra joined at a single shared vertex, by the standard definition that is not a pseudo-manifold, but a non-manifold, right?

Comment: Yes, neither pseudomanifold nor a manifold.